# How to package files into an APK archive programmatically

Tags: java, android, apk, archive

I want to programmatically create an APK file from a given path to a directory(which contains Java source code). I know this can be done from the command line using android tools, but how can it done with Java code?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  You CAN'T create an APK from JAVA.

Comment: If you know it can be done via the command line, then try to invoke the command line in Java.

Comment: @Booger I am trying to package a directory into an APK archive. Why can it not be done from Java exactly? It is just an archive, like zip, right?

Comment: How are you going to sign it? (Unless you want it unsigned)

Comment: @trevor-e Will there not be any performance/compatibility gains in doing it through pure Java code instead of doing it through cmd?

Comment: @jyoon I can probably use the jarsigner I suppose. That is the post-building process though.

Comment: You also could look to build scripts like ANT script, they might just be what you are looking but its not in java

Comment: @Pawan The performance would be negligible.  Someone already mentioned Ant.  You COULD create a Java wrapper over the Ant commands if you really wanted to, but I don't see the point of doing it in Java. See http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java/ and you could combine that with running Ant commands.

Comment: "from a given path to a directory" -- a directory of *what*? Java source code? HTML files? Pictures of cats? "It is just an archive, like zip, right?" -- it is what is *in* the archive that matters, more than the archive itself. That is why you really need to explain, in detail, by editing your question, what is in the directory that you are expecting to turn into an APK. The answer most likely is "mostly you will be running command-line binaries", simply because those binaries are what Ant, Eclipse, and Gradle use (e.g., **`javac`**, **`dx`**, **`aapt`**).

Comment: @CommonsWare You are right, I should have mentioned that. It will be Java source code. The aim is to package it for testing purposes for an Android environment. If you've ever heard of Arquillian, or ShrinkWrap, you'll know :)

Answer (score 2):

As I noted in a comment, much of the build process is handled from command-line binaries that you are unlikely to be in position to port to Java, such as **`javac`**, **`dx`**, and **`aapt`**.

If I were in your shoes, I would be looking at Gradle's IDE integration hooks and drive the build process from your Java code using that plus a suitable `build.gradle` and related files. Being able to use Gradle as The One True Build Automation System is one of the key points behind the Gradle for Android effort.

Otherwise, what you are proposing is to not use any of the existing build automation options for Android (Gradle, Ant, Maven, plus the Eclipse build process stuff), but instead build *another* one. If you have a several dozen developer-months to spare and you want to go that route, you are certainly welcome to do so. You would want to look at the aforementioned implementations for ideas.

Comment: I guess I get your point now. It makes sense. However, since the project I am working on already uses Maven, so I think it would be better if I stick to Maven instead of Gradle.
Or would you recommend going the Gradle way instead?

Comment: @Pawan: I have no experience with the Maven support for Android, so I cannot comment upon it in comparison with Gradle. That being said, I am sure it is a better solution that creating your own.

Comment: Can you please point me to the source code of the Ant file which defines how to build an android apk? Or for that matter the Gradle plugin?

Comment: @Pawan: I haven't gone looking for them. General tools-building details are at http://tools.android.com/build

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar concern and after some research, I ended up doing it by calling the command line from Java (Eclipse) and then giving as arguments the commands that I used. I repeated this in a loop for every project I wanted to build and it worked just fine.

http://geosoft.no/development/android.html This site shows every step you may need to follow for building an Android program in the command line. I was concerned only about the .apk part, so Step 14 was enough, but you can check the whole page out.

Using the APK commands in that page, I created a ProcessBuilder code:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder
        (new String[] {ANDROID_HOME + "\\build-tools\\android-4.4W\\aapt.exe",
                "package",
                "-v",
                "-f",
                "-M", projectRootDirPath + "\\AndroidManifest.xml",
                "-S", projectRootDirPath + "\\res",
                "-I", ANDROID_HOME + "\\platforms\\android-20\\android.jar",
                "-F", projectRootDirPath + "\\bin\\" + [APK_file_name] + ".apk",
                projectRootDirPath + "\\bin"});
```

ANDROID_HOME is your sdk path, projectRootDirPath is the path of the project directory and of course [APK_file_name] should be the desired name for your .apk file.

Also you might need to change the "android-4.4W" and "android-20" parts depending on the version you are using.